# Rush - memoize issues

Tags: rust, memoization

I have a game I'm trying to code and I want to memoize a `next_guess` function, as it's costly. I know there are some memoization crates, but I have some weird requirements and the whole project is an exercise in learning Rust, so I wanted to know how a true Rustacean would think about it. The `next_guess` function is in the `impl` of a `Node struct`. The game tree branches very fast, so each level has dozens of possible next step nodes to analyze. If I add a reference to the memoize `HashMap` to the `Node struct` for `next_guess` to use, I can't make it mutable, as there can't be multiple mutable references to it. But I needed it to be mutable so I can add new values. I thought using globals was a no-no, but is setting the `HashMap` as a `lazy_static` the right approach or should I use an `unsafe` block to access it (can I do that?). Thanks

Comment: Is access to the `HashMap` multithreaded? If not, you could place it within a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) so that it can be mutated behind a shared reference?  Otherwise, perhaps you could place it within a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) so that accesses across threads are synchronised (and, again, mutation can occur from behind a shared reference); however more efficient solutions exist including [parking_lot](https://crates.io/crates/parking_lot).

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents:

- Having a `HashMap` within each `Node` will consume lots of space.
- If you already have a specific `Node` at hand, do you really want to look it up in an `HashMap`? Couldn't the `Node` itself store the cached value (possibly in an `Option<BestNextGuess>`?

Comment: Sorry, for my lack of clarity. Each node currently includes a `next_guess` function, but the `HashMap` needs to be shared and universal. If I were using a memoize crate, I would pull the `next_guess` function out of the `Node impl`, but logically it belongs there. If implementing in C, I would make the `HashMap` global, so all the nodes could access it.

Comment: What's the signature of `next_guess`? What's the type of the `HashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring to create a game `struct` that owned the `HashMap` and then passed all the guess attempts through the game `struct` first before calling into the node `struct`.